# How do I search for an existing value in a SQL Database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've created a program that will allow users to log in and enter the make/model/year for the cars they own. I'd like to randomly generate a CarID to be assigned to each car that is added into the database. I've created a random number generator using the following code:

```
Random random = new Random();
int CarID = random.Next(10000);
```

And I would then insert the code in the SQL Database using:

```
SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["CarID"].DefaultValue = Convert.ToString(CarID);
```

What I'd like to do is first search the database for the number that was randomly generated to ensure it doesn't exist. If the number does exist in the database, the random number generator would try a new number until it found one that is not in the database. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Random numbers for IDs?  Sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.  What will you do if you just happen to get the same number twice?  It's not exactly unheard of.

Comment: Well that's exactly why I'm trying to see how to check for an existing number in the database, but it seems like GUIDs are what I'm looking for.

Comment: GUIDs are guaranteed (ducks around the corner) to be unique so yes, I think that's what you are looking for.  Or you can also use the auto incrementing feature which assigns a new integer value to each row as it's created.

Comment: I would recommend adding an `INT IDENTITY` column to your table, and let the database handle giving out unique ID's to each new row automatically - you won't have to worry about anything anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a GUID, not a random number.  GUIDs are stored as datatype uniqueidentifier in MS SQL Server, and they're guaranteed to be unique.  I know, it blew my mind as well.  Check out the documentation if you don't believe me, but the code to insert a row with a guid is very simple:

```
insert into someTable (id, name)
values newid(), 'some name'
```

Documentation on uniqueidentifier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for, it just seems too simple. Thanks!

Comment: Got it working using:

`Guid messageId = System.Guid.NewGuid();`

`string CarID = messageId.ToString();`

`SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["CarID"].DefaultValue = CarID;`

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an auto-incrementing identity column? Or a GUID?

Given a table with an identity column you can use this to insert your data and retrieve the new ID

```
INSERT INTO Cars
  (Make, Model, Year)
  VALUES
  'Ford', 'Festiva', 1986


SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

This is a fundamental feature of all SQL databases that you'll want to get familiar with. I'd recommend any of the Beginner SQL books on Amazon, paired with SQL for Smarties for some basic SQL data concepts.

Comment: Because I'm not familiar with either D:

Comment: Updated answer to be more explicit.

Comment: And if you need to select the new ID after inserting, I would recommend to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY`